# Why is there a "this" in the parameter list of my external C# function?

Tags: c#

My code has the following in an Action Method:

```
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log(e);
        return Content(ExceptionExtensions.GetFormattedErrorMessage(e));
    }
```

The function called looks like this:

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static string GetFormattedErrorMessage(this Exception e)

            if (e == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
        }
```

Can someone explain why there is a "this" at the start of the parameter list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the signature of the extension methods. They were introduced in .NET3.5(C#3). Without `this` the compiler would take it as a static method signature.
in the following code:

```
public class Foo
{
    public void FooBar()
    {

    }
}
public static class FooEx
{
    public static void Bar(this Foo f)
    {
        f.FooBar();
    }
    public static void StaticBar(Foo f)
    {
        f.FooBar();
    }
}
```

You can call the static method like this:

```
FooEx.StaticBar(new Foo());
```

and the extension method like this:

```
new Foo().Bar();
```

and the extension method as a static method:

```
FooBar.Bar(new Foo());
```

So, to convert an extension method to static method all you have to do is remove the `this` keyword from the signature.
However, if you want to convert a static method into an extension methods you have to:

1. Add the `this` keyword to the signature
2. Put the method into a non-nested `public static` class
3. Make the access modifier of the method `public`

[Scott Hanselman has a good article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx) on the choice of the syntax and how it fit the existing CLR with minimal changes to the compiler.

In summary, he concludes that after compilation, there is no difference between the generated IL code for a static method and the code for an extension method.
The `this` keyword is there to instruct the compiler to put some meta data around the extension method.

My guess is that they have gone for the `this` keyword because 1.it already existed  and 2. its existing meaning best fitted in the context of the extension method compared to the other existing keywords.

Comment: Maybe add something that the OP can call the function this way: `e.GetFormattedErrorMessage()`.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but can you guess any reason why it was coded this way. Also if I wanted to change this to a static method, how could I do that and what would be the disadvantage?

Comment: @SamanthaJ extension methods *are* static methods, and they may be called using *either* the normal static method syntax or the extension method (quasi-instance-method) syntax.  For that reason, I believe, the current example will not compile, though I don't have a compiler handy to check.

Comment: @SamanthaJ yes, you are right. I typed the example straight into the browser. I have edited the answer.

Comment: I checked the code on ideone, and in fact it doesn't compile, so -1.

Comment: @phoog yes, I know. See above.

Comment: ok, I changed the down vote to an up vote.  I can't seem to delete the previous comment in my phone's browser.

Answer (score 2):

because that's how you define an 'extension' method. it lets the compiler know that this particular method should be allowed to be called directly on an object, it lets you write code like this:

```
GetFormattedErrorMessage(e);
```

instead as:

```
e.GetFormattedErrorMessage();
```

i'm not sure why the code you posted is calling the function in that way. you should be able to call the function directly on the exception object. extension methods are essentially ways to extend behavior of built in classes/types that you otherwise wouldn't be able to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Extension method as already mentioned, some links:

- [Extension Methods (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)
- [How to: Implement and Call a Custom Extension Method (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx)
- [A tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/)

Plus the usual dozens of blog posts and other documentation from Google.

Answer (score -1):

"this" is the error that is being passed to the Exception method, similar to using "this" in a function. It is simply referring to the exception that is being passed.

Comment: -1: no, "`this`" is the `Exception` that is being passed to the `GetFormattedErrorMessage` extension method.